# Set test information in body of POST request for .NET Request.Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, testing, http-post, fiddler

I'm not entirely sure how to word the title for the best. But I know I've done this before and can't seem to find out how to do this.

I have a method like this

```
[HttpPost]
public string doSomething()
{
   string formValue = Request.Form["MyKey"];
   return formValue;
}
```

Then I send up a fiddler POST sample request.

I put something like this in the Request body

```
MyKey=SomeValue
```

However, when I invoke fiddler I get a null formValue string.

I know i've done this before, I just can't seem to remember how to pass this information in the body of the request.

Comment: Possibly you forgot to set the content-type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: The content-type is it totally forgot, thanks Cameron! Go ahead and answer it so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, here's my comment in the form of an answer:

---

Possibly you forgot to set the content-type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

This is necessary in order for the body to be understood to be containing form data.